# XSLT 1.0 Foreach less than and greater than

Tags: xslt-1.0

Is is possible in a foreach loop to get a greater than and a lesser than position in the same statement.

Currently I have 
          `<xsl:for-each select="(/*/Request/InvoiceDetailRequest/InvoiceDetailOrder/InvoiceDetailItem)[10 &gt;= position()]">`

But I want  `<xsl:for-each select="(/*/Request/InvoiceDetailRequest/InvoiceDetailOrder/InvoiceDetailItem)[10 &gt;= position()] and [10 &lt;= position()">`

This doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put both halves of the predicate condition in the same set of square brackets:

```
(....)[(10 &gt;= position()) and (5 &lt;= position())]
```